# Andriond send event from first activity and receive on the second

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. The first activity display list of the users with short info. And after   select some user I go to the second activity for display full info  about this user. For send event I used `startActivityForResult();` for receive event in socond activity and added     `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. After start project I send intend from first activity  and I do not receive in the second :(. How I can receive sent event  in second activity?
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement onActivityResult in the first activity in order to get the result from the sub-activity you've started. In your sub-activity you receive the event in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    // Do some setup based on the action being performed.

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals()) {
    }

}
```

I recommend that you have a look at the Notepad sample to see how things work. startActivityForResult may not be needed - startActivity should be enough. You usually don't return something from the item view to the list view.